# Write a server request to file in Node

Tags: node.js, json

I am curious how I could write a server request in my node application to a JSON file.

So far I have a simple event listener for my server that writes the data to a file but every time I read the file it simply says `[object object]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => { 
 fs.writeFile('userData.json', req, 'utf8', () => {
    console.log(req);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object doesn't override the `toString` method (as `req` doesn't), you'll get `[Object object]` when treating it in a string context (e.g., writing it to a file). One approach to solve this is to explicitly convert the object to JSON:

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => { 
 const jsonString = JSON.stringify(req);
 fs.writeFile('userData.json', jsonString, 'utf8', () => {
    console.log(jsonString);
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

To address the issue in the comment, `JSON.stringify` doesn't handle circular references properly. You could use a 3rd party like [flatted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted) instead:

```
const flatted = require('flatted');
server.on('request', (req, res) => { 
 const jsonString = flatted.stringify(req);
 fs.writeFile('userData.json', jsonString, 'utf8', () => {
    console.log(jsonString);
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this approach and an error was thrown. TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON     at JSON.stringify